# Linux distro for cloning Windows SSDs, to run from a pendrive

Tags: linux, disk-image

I will have to back up a few SSDs to the cloud, and clone my Windows installation from one SSD to another. What's the easiest Linux distribution to do so? I could use `dd` on pretty much any distribution, but having access to graphical interface, and software like CloneZilla that offers progress bar, would improve my quality of life when doing it. Support for wireless networking would also help greatly, to push images to my NAS.

Answer (score 1):

Clonezilla has a bootable "live" image (I've never tried it though)

GParted is another option with a live image. It's been great for partition clones for me. Web browsing isn't something I've done, but I've heard it has some sort of web browser.

I think the ubuntu live image comes with gparted and a browser, I think that might be the easiest way to do it. (You could install packages while it runs too) I might try this first.

If you're doing this multiple times it might be worth setting up some non-live distribution (ubuntu is popular) on an external hard drive with persistence. That would let you do things like save credentials and install software that will stay around after a reboot.